# Using decltype with an operator using non-ADL lookup

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I have the following (contrived) code:

```cpp
#include <utility>

namespace N
{
  struct A {};
  struct B {};
}

namespace operators
{
  bool operator|(N::A, N::B) { return true; };
}

namespace details
{
  using namespace operators;

  template<typename T, typename U>
  using UnionResultType = decltype(std::declval<T>() | std::declval<U>());
}

int main()
{
  {
    using namespace operators;
    using UnionAB = decltype(std::declval<N::A>() | std::declval<N::B>());
    static_assert(std::is_same<UnionAB, bool>::value);
  }

  {
    using UnionAB = details::UnionResultType<N::A, N::B>;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

GCC has a problem compiling the `UnionAB` declaration in the second block:

```
operators.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class T, class U> using UnionResultType = decltype
((declval<T>() | declval<U>())) [with T = N::A; U = N::B]’:
operators.cpp:31:56:   required from here
operators.cpp:19:54: error: no match for ‘operator|’ (operand types are ‘N::A’ and ‘N::B’)
using UnionResultType = decltype(std::declval<T>() | std::declval<U>());
```

Even though there is a `using namespace operators` within the scope defining the templated `UnionResultType`, GCC fails to find the operator overload.

I am using GCC 7.2.0 (C++11, 14, and 17 mode all have the same problem).

Is there some issue in the code, or is this a compiler issue? In case this is a compiler issue, is this a known issue?

Comment: Of interest is that [an explicit `operator|` lookup works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04d948ee5ec14e76).  BTW, using declarations can behave differently if you are a siblign or a parent namespace of what you are using; I'd ensure the code you are using is a sibling.

Comment: Also, [clang accepts it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f653636e8ef6105f)

Comment: @Yakk, interesting, thanks. I am going to wade through the GCC bug tracker then...

Comment: MSVC also accepts it. I think your code is well-formed.

Comment: Filed a bug report for this issue: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83035